# Running scripts only on clicked objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem seems pretty easy to solve in my head, but it seems harder to do in unity. Basically i want to make a simulation of 3-4 conveyors system. Right now i have a conveyor in the scene and i can insert how many conveyors i want from clicking a button. Also, i have 2 sliders which control the scale of the conveyor(length and width), but when i move them, all conveyors scale to same dimension. What i want to do, is that the scale works only on one conveyor at time, the conveyor i click after the scene is played. Any of you have any idea how should i do this? Thank you in advance! The scaling code is :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScaleWithSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider z;

    public Slider x;





    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(x.value, 25f, z.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your scaling-code? How do you reference the conveyor that should be scaled?

Comment: I edited the post and inserted the code also, basically the script works on the conveyor and scales the "object" to which is attached

Comment: So this script is on ever conveyer? Do you have individual sliders for every conveyer instance?

Comment: this script will only change the object if something changes the values, as a cipy of the script is on each object if one scripts x changes, none of the others do unless you manually change all of them

Comment: slider values goes from 0 to 25, and when i drag the sliders, the value of z and x changes

Comment: @BugFinder 
public void AddObject()
 {
        insertedobj = Instantiate(conveyor, spawnpos.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 }
This is the code i use for spawning new game objects when the button is clicked, where the conveyor is my initial conveyor from the scene that has the scalling sliders attached

Comment: Im with aalmigjty sounds like the sliders code says change all

Comment: @aalmigthy no, i don't have sliders for every instance, i have only 2 sliders, what i want to do, is that they work only on the clicked object, and not on all of them

Comment: I have 2 sliders, one that scales on X and one that scales on Z, and the script is attached to the initial conveyor, which i clone when i run the AddObject function, the problem is that after the object spawns, if i move change the slider values, all conveyors scale with the same ratio, what i want to do, is that the scalling sliders to work only on clicked object

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict the `slider` to the active `conveyor`.

There are a million ways to implement it, you could implement some kind of controller approach like this.

The scale class tells the controller if it was clicked on. This can also be done by any other class.
Scaling is only applied when this conveyor is selected.

```
    public class ScaleWithSlider : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Slider z;
        public Slider x;

        private bool _respondsToSlider;
        private ConveyorController _conveyorController;

        private void Start()
        {
            _conveyorController = GetComponentInParent<ConveyorController>();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (!_respondsToSlider) return;

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(x.value, 25f, z.value);
        }

        public void SetRespondsToSlider(bool respondsToSlider)
        {
            _respondsToSlider = respondsToSlider;
        }

        private void OnMouseDown()
        {
            // any other way of getting the active conveyor would also work
            _conveyorController.SetActiveConveyor(this);
        }
```

The Controller class makes sure only one conveyer is active:

```
    public class ConveyorController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // this list must filled somehow. best would be right after Instantiating the conveyer.
        private List<ScaleWithSlider> _allSliderScalers;

        public void SetActiveConveyor(ScaleWithSlider scaleWithSlider)
        {
            foreach (var conveyor in _allSliderScalers)
            {
                conveyor.SetRespondsToSlider(conveyor == scaleWithSlider);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you wanted to check here, the problem is that when i click the slider to change the value, the OnMouseDown() sets to off. In the OnMouseDown function i also added GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red; to check if the code is working, but when i click the conveyer it gives me this errorNullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Do you have another way to assign the current selected conveyor to the `ConveyorController`? I don't understand your implementation enough to be able to give more specific hints. You can edit the question and add more details, perhaps that would help me.

Comment: I have no other way to assign the curent selected conveyor, i just made a new script [ConveyorController] and assigned it to the initial conveyor, the only thing i changed in the scripts you gave me was that in [ScaleWithSlider] script, inside the OnMouseDown() function, i added GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;which, from what i learnt earlier, should change the color of clicked objects to red. But when i click an object ,i get the error i mentioned in the last comment

Comment: Most likely you don't have a `Renderer` on the object and therefore it gives the `NullReferenceException`. You can try to log using `Debug.Log("Clicked " + name)` to have it printed to the `Console` when an object is clicked.

Comment: Also the `ScaleWithSlider` looks at a parent object for the `ConveyorController`, you need to change it according to your GameObject hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

as [@aalmigthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429710/9484776) mentioned, there are many ways to do this, The most straight forward one is, On each mouse click store the clicked conveyer object reference in a `scenemanager` and when the slider value changes, apply it to the stored conveyer object instance from the `scenemanager` (rather than from the conveyor object instance, like how it is being done now) by saying something like:

```
currentConveyer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x.value, 25f, z.value);
```